# How to implement Cloud Monitoring Uptime checks for instances without external IP ( private websites )

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-stackdriver

[Cloud Monitoring Uptime checks](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks) allow users to send a request to a resource to see if it respond.

Since the checks are performed outside Google Cloud infrastructure, an [external ip is needed](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks#before_you_begin).

Is there a way to implement Uptime checks for sites ( http requests ) that does not have a public IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: yes, by using a bastion host with external IP that can query reach the internal site and use a proxy ( NGINX , SquidProxy , etc ) to pass your health check request from the external services to your internal sites.

## What you need:

1. A VM with external IP in the same [VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc) of your private [VMS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances) ( the ones without public ip).
2. Communication between the VM with external IP (from now referred as *probe vm* ) and the VMs that host your internal websites.
3. (optional, but highly recommended) Your website should have a health-check webpage. This page should return a 200 if the site and system it’s ok and preferably an authentication protection.

## The process:

1. Create a VM within the same VPC where your internal website is. You can create [basic linux VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux) running your preferred linux distribution. The size of your VM can be a [n1-standard-1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#n1_machine_type) or a  [e2-standard-2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#e2_machine_types) the size really depends on how many sites you will monitor. You may need to adjust the size of your VM according to your needs.
2. Allow communication between your *probe vm* and the internal vms that host your site. It’s recommended that you only allow the ports used by your internal sites.
3. Restrict all traffic to your your *probe vm* to avoid any type of data leak. Use [Google Cloud Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) to achieve this. ( note: do not forget to whitelist your IP for port 22 so you can manage your *probe vm* )
4. Allow HTTP (port 80) traffic to your *probe vm* to [Cloud Monitoring ips](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/using-uptime-checks#get-ips).
5. Install [NGINX Opensource](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/) on your *probe vm*.

If you want to skip the installation process, you may choose to use [NGINX PLUS](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-plus-google-cloud-platform/) and install it by using [Google Cloud MarketPlace](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace)

You can also use [NGINX Docker container](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-docker/#docker_oss) for this task.

6. Configure [NGINX as Reverse Proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)
7. Create your [Uptime checks in Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks#monitoring_uptime_check_create-console).

### Some tips and tricks on how to configure nginx

When you install NGINX by following NGINX’s instructions, you will get a functional NGINX at the end of the process. But you may need extra configurations to achieve the goal.

1. Modify the file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` to answer a 404 to any request that does not includes a valid HOST header:

```
server {
    listen       80 default;
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

2. Create a configuration file under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` directory for each site you want to monitor. i.e. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/finance-sites.conf`. Do not forget the .conf termination.
3. Set a bogus host for each site you want to monitor and do not forget to set the host header in [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks#advanced_options).
4. Do not forget to check syntax `nginx -t` and reload configuration `nginx -s reload` each time you perform a change in your configuration.